# Change SVN password command line

Tags: security, svn, command-line, passwords

How do I change the SVN password from command line?

It is the best way for me if it can be done from the command line.

Comment: I though before that SVN has authentication of the host system Unix names server or LDAP. But seems like it can also maintain it's own creds storage.. clear text on file system

Comment: What is the access protocol? HTTP/HTTPs, over SSH or the SVN-proprietary one?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You must edit a file under your `/repo/conf/passwd` using a command line editor like [Vim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_%28text_editor%29).
There is no way to do this with Subversion command-line utilities like `svnadmin`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Seems like i can not access it

Comment: svn: '/svn/../conf/passwd' path not found

Comment: In my example change `/repo` with your full repository path, that was only an example.

Comment: Look at a simple tutorial like [this](http://www.systhread.net/texts/200607subver.php).
It may be useful.

Comment: i understand that the path you mean is relative to repository.

Comment: the point is I am not the admin of this SVN, I do not have access to the admin machine. From the other side i can not give my password to admin and say "please change ma pass from qwerty to 12345"

Comment: You cannot change a password if you are not an admin (obviously for security reasons). You must ask for an administrator to change it for you.

Comment: OK, seems like there is no question to my answer. The reason is in configuration of my SVN. I see that only admins can change the password here. This is weird.

Comment: Thanks everybody for your answers!! I will mark this answer, because it is closest to the question i asked.

Answer (score 18):

There are multiple ways passwords are setup on Subversion. It depends upon the server you're using (svnserve, http, svn+ssh), and the way the administrator has set everything up.

Subversion doesn't contain a built in authentication method. Instead, it can use many different external authentication methods from the very simple to the extremely complex. Some will allow users to change their own passwords and even setup their own accounts. Others require a system administrator to do it. It all depends upon your particular setup.

- On our site, we use Apache http to serve our Subversion repository (`svn co http://server/src/repos`). I've set it up to use our Windows Active Directory, so the user's username and password is their Windows' username and password. It means I don't have to handle users' *I forgot my password* requests, and passed the whole account headache to our Windows administrators.
- Some sites use Apache http, but use a password file located on the Apache server itself. This is usually called `htpasswd` and its location is configured by the Subversion administrator. It's possible that the System administrator has a way to let the users set their own passwords, but that's not necessarily true. In this instance, you have to contact the administrator and ask them to change your password.
- Some sites use `svnserve` (`svn co svn://server/repos`). The standard way this is setup is that there's a `passwd` file in the Subversion repository's `config` directory. This is located on the system that's running the server, and you have no access to it. Again, you have to contact the system administrator.
- Some sites use [SASL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Authentication_and_Security_Layer) for their authentication. This can use Windows Active Directory, LDAP, or any number of authentication methods. Sometimes you can set your own password, sometimes you have to ask the administrator how it's done.

So, you're going to have to ask your Subversion administrator how to change your password. If you're lucky, there's a way to do it yourself. If not, you'll have to ask your Subversion administrator to change it.

Answer (score 4):

If *https* is used, the password may be defined by Apache. This is what I needed to do to change password, in case it helps someone else:

```
# using root account
cd /etc/apache2
cat foo.passwd # the right user, foobar was found here
# copy the line for foobar, in case you want to restore it!
man htpasswd # a little refresher on what the command does
htpasswd foo.passwd foobar
# new password is prompted
cat foo.passwd # check that the line for this user actually got changed
```

Then do checkout with *https* to verify the right password got changed.

Comment: This did it for me `sudo htpasswd /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd theUserName`

Answer (score 2):

This is what I have to do:

```
cd /etc/httpd/conf/svn
```

backup current svn-auth just in case

```
cp svn-auth.htdigest svn-auth.htdigest«yymmDD»
htdigest svn-auth.htdigest “Subversion Repository” «user-name»
```

It was ask for new passwsord

Answer (score 1):

`htpasswd -m C:\csvn\data\conf\svn_auth_file admin`

Answer (score -1):

I recommend installing the Collabnet SubVersion Edge bundle, since it includes a Web tool for allowing users to change their passwords on their own.